# Is there a way to to stop aws-iam-authenticator from using secret keys from environment?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, kubectl, amazon-eks

Problem
My env has some AWS keys and still I want my kubectl which is using aws-iam-authenticator to authenticate against EKS to use the role associated to the ec2 instance. 
I tried using below mentioned snippet in .kube/config however aws-iam-authenticator still gives more presendence to env variables.

```
- name: eks
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      command: aws-iam-authenticator
      args:
      - token
      - -i
      - eks-build-systems
      env:
      - name: AWS_PROFILE
        value: ec2-role
```

Here ec2-role is defined in the .aws/config file and points to the ec2 role associated to instance.

Any ideas if there is a way to avoid this behavior without being forced to unset the env variables?

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation please "**Use the AWS CLI update-kubeconfig command to create or update your kubeconfig for your cluster**" you can find more information [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-kubeconfig.html), and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/eks/update-kubeconfig.html).

After creation new kubeconfig:

> *Add that file path to your KUBECONFIG environment variable so that kubectl knows where to look for your cluster configuration*.

Temporarily like in the example `export KUBECONFIG=$KUBECONFIG:~/.kube/config-devel`
 or permanently `echo 'export KUBECONFIG=$KUBECONFIG:~/.kube/config-devel' >> ~/.bashrc`

As per documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/configuring-sdk.html#specifying-credentials):

> When you initialize a new service client without providing any credential arguments, the SDK uses the default credential provider chain to find AWS credentials. The SDK uses the first provider in the chain that returns credentials without an error. The default provider chain looks for credentials in the following order:
>
> 1. Environment variables.
> 2. Shared credentials file.
> 3. If your application is running on an Amazon EC2 instance, IAM role for Amazon EC2.
>
> By default, the SDK checks the AWS_PROFILE environment variable to determine which profile to use. If **no AWS_PROFILE** variable is set, the SDK uses the **default profile**.

On the other hand you can create as many profiles as you want `aws/credentials`. You can find more information [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-iam-authenticator):

> This method allows the appropriate profile to be used implicitly. Note that any environment variables set as part of the exec flow will take precedence over what's already set in your environment

Comment: thanks for your response my problem is little different. I want my kubectl to use the aws profile given in kubeconfig file even if there are AWS secret keys available in env. It looks like this priority i set by the underlying aws skd implemented in boto and  though it's behaving as expected I was wondeing if there is a way to suppress this behavior.

Comment: New informations were added. Please share with your results.